# Uniform convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}x^n $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms, uniform-convergence

I treid to show that $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}x^n = \log(1+x)$$ for $\mid x\mid <1$ by showing that $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} x^{n-1} = \frac {1}{x+1}$$ uniformly and then integrate both sides of equation due to uniform convergence. But we know that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1}$ doesn't converge uniformly for $\mid x\mid <1$ so I can not use Abel's test.

Thanks for any help to show $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}x^n = \log(1+x)$ for $\mid x\mid <1$.

Comment: Why do you say $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1}$ doesn't converge uniformly for $\mid x\mid <1$? Use cauchy hadamard and you get $R=1$.

Comment: @metamorphy I dont understand. If the radius of convergence is 1, doesn't that means that the series converges on $(-1,1)$ and because it is a power series it converges uniformly there?

Comment: @eminem: The convergence *on $(-1,1)$* is *not uniform*. Yes, the series is uniformly convergent on $(-r,r)$ for $r<1$, but that's all. (This doesn't really matter to answer the question; that's why I've deleted my prior comment.)

Comment: (The [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) can be used to justify the equality at $x=1$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x\in(-1,1)$ and take $r\in(|x|,1)$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-1}$ converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$ to $\frac1{x+1}$. And so$$(\forall t\in[-r,r]):\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^t(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx=\log(t+1).$$In particular, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}nx^n=\log(x+1)$.